# How to get the information of users connected to a Wi-Fi hotspot?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

How can I get the IP address, MAC address, etc. of a user connected to a Wi-Fi hotspot? ( Using Karbonn A21 Phone running Android 4.0.4 with minor changes to the skin)