# How to view devices connected to hotspot on Android?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

This has been asked for [a](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46649/how-to-get-the-information-of-users-connected-to-a-wi-fi-hotspot) [few](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18529/how-do-i-check-who-is-connecting-to-my-hotspot?noredirect=1&lq=1) [times](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/169548/how-can-an-android-phone-acting-as-a-local-hotspot-show-how-many-people-are-conn) before, but none recently or with the Pixel/Nougat specifically that I was able to find.  Root is unavailable, so I need a way to do this as a regular user.  I really just want to see what IP my Raspberry Pi got assigned by the Android DHCP.  Also, if there's a way to set DHCP reservations to avoid having to look it up every time, I would love to know how to do that as well.

Comment: You won't find DHCP reservations but I observed that devices tend to get the same IP address they had earlier (don't know the time frame, though).

Comment: How about using third-party applications? I use Pixel Netcut for that. I also have a feeling Tasker can do this, but I will have to figure it out

Comment: @xavier_fakerat I'd be willing to use one if needed (and feel free to write up an answer if you have something in mind).  When I searched the app store, most things seemed geared towards the phone connecting to a wifi router and then viewing networks on that device.  I didn't come across something that did exactly what I wanted (and was free, which would be my preference.)

Comment: Honestly, I attached an LCD screen to my pi and got that to just output its IP, which resolved my personal problem, but I still would like to know the best way to address this for other devices in the future and think that it's a useful question others will undoubted have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the solutions known to me require root (as I noted in comments). However there is a third-party application that seems to be able to handle this task as well.

[Hotspot manager<sup>1</sup>](https://www.appbrain.com/app/com.etustudio.android.hotspotmanager) claims to be able to monitor all connected clients on the hotspot. It gives the **MAC Address** as well as **IP address** of connected clients

Some other features include:

- Managing multiple WiFi hotspots for different scenarios.
- Monitoring all connected clients to your device.
- WiFi auto recovery: WiFi state will be recovered if the hotspot is turned off (assuming either widget or the app to toggle).

See screenshots:

[image] [image]

---

<sup>1: This app is no longer available on Play Store.</sup>

Comment: This app is not working anymore on even Android 7

Comment: App crashes on Android 13

Comment: Hello, try to use terminal

Answer (score 32):

Another  "uglier" workaround involves using terminal , but it has an advantage if you already have terminal installed in your device.

Simply type `ip neigh` in terminal and you should see an output showing connected devices' **ip addresses** as well as **mac address** (but it looks a bit cluttered though)

See screenshot:

[image]

<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

The information in the terminal output includes
:

- **IP address** of connected client
- **MAC address** (obscured in screenshot)
- interface (`wlan0`)
- state of connection (i.e STALE, REACHABLE etc)

Note: This **does not need** root permissions

Comment: This is the method that works even on Android 11. If you are using termux, make sure to install the iproue2 package.

Comment: On Android 13 I get `Cannot bind netlink socket: Permission denied`

Answer (score 9):

On the stock HTC tethering app, there is a view called "Manage users" which lets you see a list of connected devices listed be resolved hostname. Touching each device reveals its hardware address and currently assigned IP address.

[image: HTC tethering app - manage users]

As far as I can recall it is the same for the stock Samsung Galaxy S2 (at least in this region - Northern Europe).

Comment: There's nothing like this for Galaxy SII.

Answer (score 9):

If you've got access to a terminal on your phone (I guess that requires being rooted), then you can also run `ip neigh show dev wlan0` to see what's in the ARP tables.

That should tell you the MAC addresses and IP addresses of everything connected.

Comment: In some cases, it would be ap0 not wlan0, but the best is to simply type `ip neigh`. And yes, it does need root access.

Comment: This doesn't require root, btw. Just a terminal app.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me. `ip neigh show dev bt-pan` for anyone else with a Bluetooth hot spot.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Network Discovery<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>](https://www.appbrain.com/app/info.lamatricexiste.network) -- it lists all devices within the same network, together with some details on them, as e.g. IP, MAC address, available services:

[image: Network Discovery] [image: Network Discovery]
<sup>Network Discovery (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

Other port scanners will do as well.

---

<sup><sup>1: This app is no longer available on Play Store.</sup></sup>

Comment: Does it scan the WiFi hotspot the phone creates or/and the WiFi network to which the phone's connected ? (I'm asking this because I don't have my phone right now)

Comment: It does scan the network the device is *in.* I don't think it matters if it itself is "master" or "client" in the network -- but I never tried.

Comment: It would be needed to enable in options 3G scanning.

Comment: @Vadzim not much chances. I'd bet port-scanning is blocked there by the providers/carriers for good reasons. Apart from that, the question was about WiFi, not 3G ;)

Comment: @Izzy, I was solving the problem of finding MAC of one device connected to Wi-Fi hotspot of the second device. The first device was in process of initial setup not allowing to view MAC from inside.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Fing - Network Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing). It's a clean way for your task.

Comment: Fing worked, though not quite in the way I had expected. It can't actually see the hotspot from the phone. However, it works great from my tablet which is generally the reason that I turn on the hotspot anyways. Thanks

Comment: Fing doesn't scan the phone's hotspot, only the wifi network to which the phone is connected.  This answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is [Wifi Watch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riverdevs.whosinmywifi).

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? Link-only answers are not considered that helpful. What details does it offer?

Comment: Sorry! but the questions says that it should work for `mobile as hotspots`. Wifi Watch is not for that. It scans if your `mobile is connected to wifi hotspot`

Answer (score 1):

Use [Ksiri tool](http://karthiksiriapps.blogspot.com/p/ksiri-android-tools.html) to list devices connected to your hotspot.

[image: IMG:]

Updated information on request:
I was facing same issue on my Android Oreo, some tools on net available is filled with ads or asking for unnecessary permissions.

Just for this simple listing of which devices are connected, ads and special permissions, both were not necessary, so I have created this app, which will not ask for any permissions and neither shows any ads.

This is the first step of "Ksiri Tools" that I have created, further if any tooling things comes up, I will add same app.

I have not released any of my apps on play store, as I feel it's unnecessary to pay Google.
You can download apk file and install. While installing you will be clearly shown by Android that this app doesn't require any permissions.
So safe to use.