# Check IP details via Android Terminal App in Android 13

Tags: permissions, terminal, android-13

Seems that **Android 13** doesn't allow any more access to **`/system/bin/ip`** command.

I tried to list the connected hotspot devices via `ip neigh` [[1](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/174728/378626)].

The error message is:

[image: ip neith \ Cannot bind netlink socket: Permission denied]

> Cannot bind netlink socket: Permission denied

Is there any way to fix that issue in Android 13?

So far I tried it with the following terminal apps

- [Temux](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.termux/) <s>[v0.101](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux)</s> [v0.118.0](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.termux/) (via F-Droid)
- [Terminal Emulator for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) v1.0.70

---

- [1] [How to view devices connected to hotspot on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/174728/378626)

Comment: Termux in Google PlayStore is no longer updated (because of Google restrictions), you should switch to [Termux F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.termux/) version.

Comment: @Robert I don't think the Google Play version is kind of related here since it's still possible to do what the OP wants on Android 12, but I could be wrong...

Comment: That said, does calling `ip` command without flags return anything? (the screenshot shows a typo `neith`, which would show `Object "neith" is unknown, try "ip help"` on Android 12)

Comment: Deinstalled Termux and updated to v0.118.0. Now the command `ip` returns, that it is not installed, and I can do that via `iproute2` or `termux-tools` package. I'll try that now...

Comment: @AndrewT. now `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ip` comes with the same error: `Cannot bind netlink socket: Permission denied`.

Comment: @AndrewT. in Android 13 with the `iproute2` package `man ip` and the search for `ip neigh` says: `Shows the current neighbour table in kernel`.

Comment: [The error](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/v5.19.0/lib/libnetlink.c#L232) comes because the [bind](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) call fails. Most probably it's due to the restricted SELinux policy as was the case with UNIX domain sockets. You can try to check AVC denials in kernel log. Hopefully it'll still be working on ADB shell.

Answer (score 4):

Google has removed the possibility to `bind netlink socket` to retrieve `arp` table from `targetSdkVersion 30` through SELinux policies. If you have root, you can disable SELinux policies and it will work, giving the command `su -c setenforce 0` when you're done with `ip neigh` command, I suggest you to enforce SELinux policies again with command `su -c setenforce 1`

Without using `bind` function, I've made a library that does a workaround that consist in sending via `netlink socket` a type message not listed (30) and then I've used the socket receive to see which data system returns to that socket. From that, I've noticed that the received data was the `arp` table.

You can find more here https://github.com/fulvius31/ip-neigh-sdk30/blob/main/ipneigh30/src/main/cpp/ip_neigh.c

Comment: *@fulvius31* is your library implemented in any public app?

Comment: Yes. Mine called WeeNet [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sangiorgisrl.wifimanagertool&hl=en&gl=US)

Comment: @fulvius31 I can't get your library to work when the targetsdkversion is set to 32 or above and being run on Android 13 device. The message "socket send failed" is being shown in Logcat.

Comment: @Dieter27 I can confirm that the library does not work with Android 13 and `targetSdk` setted to `32` otherwise it works.